# How to train LSTM model in Keras using multiple time series sequences for fine tuning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

**The description of my work.**

1. I have multiple execution traces(sequences) of the same application. One execution trace is different from another execution trace and written to the separate CSV file.
2. Similarly, I have multiple execution traces of different applications.
3. Now I want to build an **LSTM** model that will be trained by multiple sequences.
4. one sequence's updated weight will be preserved for further tuning/fine tuning by another sequence.

Snapshot of the Training Model code as follows:

```
# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(n_seq, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(n_seq))
for i in range(0,10):
    model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # Prepare data for LSTM
    train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y = 
                 prepare_training_data(each time for seperate sequence)
        history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=nb_epoch, 
           batch_size=n_batch, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

But the problem is after each fit call my LSTM model's network weight is getting reset(from my understanding and observation) instead of retaining the previous weights of the network?

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere?

Kindly help me to figure out how to propagate the previously trained network weight for fine tuning on the new sequence?

I am attaching my findings below.

Sequence 1:

```
Train on 448 samples, validate on 128 samples
Epoch 1/10
- 0s - loss: 0.3213 - acc: 0.3795 - val_loss: 0.1987 - val_acc: 0.4219
Epoch 2/10
- 0s - loss: 0.2046 - acc: 0.3460 - val_loss: 0.1980 - val_acc: 0.3047
Epoch 3/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1766 - acc: 0.3192 - val_loss: 0.1874 - val_acc: 0.4141
Epoch 4/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1773 - acc: 0.3571 - val_loss: 0.1867 - val_acc: 0.3047
Epoch 5/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1728 - acc: 0.3192 - val_loss: 0.1840 - val_acc: 0.2266
Epoch 6/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1660 - acc: 0.3571 - val_loss: 0.1843 - val_acc: 0.3203
Epoch 7/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1641 - acc: 0.3304 - val_loss: 0.1834 - val_acc: 0.3828
Epoch 8/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1599 - acc: 0.4330 - val_loss: 0.1835 - val_acc: 0.4219
Epoch 9/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1576 - acc: 0.4241 - val_loss: 0.1834 - val_acc: 0.4531
Epoch 10/10
- 0s - loss: 0.1555 - acc: 0.4487 - val_loss: 0.1829 - val_acc: 0.4766
acc: 47.66%`
```

Sequence 2:

```
Train on 512 samples, validate on 160 samples
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.45000, saving model to model.h5
- 1s - loss: 0.1473 - acc: 0.3828 - val_loss: 0.1546 - val_acc: 0.4500

Epoch 2/10
Epoch 00002: val_acc did not improve 
- 0s - loss: 0.1433 - acc: 0.3867 - val_loss: 0.1553 - val_acc: 0.4250

Epoch 3/10
Epoch 00003: val_acc improved from 0.45000 to 0.45625, saving model to model.h5 
- 0s - loss: 0.1432 - acc: 0.4180 - val_loss: 0.1535 - val_acc: 0.4562

Epoch 4/10
Epoch 00004: val_acc improved from 0.45625 to 0.47500, saving model to model.h5 
- 0s - loss: 0.1421 - acc: 0.4238 - val_loss: 0.1545 - val_acc: 0.4750

Epoch 5/10
Epoch 00005: val_acc did not improve 
- 0s - loss: 0.1413 - acc: 0.4004 - val_loss: 0.1564 - val_acc: 0.4562

Epoch 6/10
Epoch 00006: val_acc improved from 0.47500 to 0.51250, saving model to model.h5 
- 0s - loss: 0.1405 - acc: 0.4258 - val_loss: 0.1562 - val_acc: 0.5125

Epoch 7/10
Epoch 00007: val_acc did not improve 
- 0s - loss: 0.1394 - acc: 0.4785 - val_loss: 0.1527 - val_acc: 0.512

Epoch 8/10
Epoch 00008: val_acc improved from 0.51250 to 0.52500, saving model to model.h5 
- 0s - loss: 0.1375 - acc: 0.4629 - val_loss: 0.1502 - val_acc: 0.5250

Epoch 9/10
Epoch 00009: val_acc did not improve 
- 0s - loss: 0.1361 - acc: 0.4551 - val_loss: 0.1484 - val_acc: 0.4688

Epoch 10/10
Epoch 00010: val_acc did not improve 
- 0s - loss: 0.1355 - acc: 0.4648 - val_loss: 0.1473 - val_acc: 0.4750
acc: 47.50%
```

Sequence 3:

```
Train on 480 samples, validate on 128 samples
Epoch 1/10
Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.41406, saving model to model.h5
- 1s - loss: 0.1342 - acc: 0.3937 - val_loss: 0.1275 - val_acc: 0.4141

Epoch 2/10
Epoch 00002: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1363 - acc: 0.4313 - val_loss: 0.1308 - val_acc: 0.3047

Epoch 3/10
Epoch 00003: val_acc improved from 0.41406 to 0.44531, saving model to model.h5
- 0s - loss: 0.1352 - acc: 0.4479 - val_loss: 0.1289 - val_acc: 0.4453

Epoch 4/10
Epoch 00004: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1324 - acc: 0.4188 - val_loss: 0.1273 - val_acc: 0.3438

Epoch 5/10
Epoch 00005: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1301 - acc: 0.4333 - val_loss: 0.1253 - val_acc: 0.4453

Epoch 6/10
Epoch 00006: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1309 - acc: 0.4583 - val_loss: 0.1243 - val_acc: 0.4141

Epoch 7/10
Epoch 00007: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1338 - acc: 0.4375 - val_loss: 0.1329 - val_acc: 0.4375

Epoch 8/10
Epoch 00008: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1340 - acc: 0.4479 - val_loss: 0.1235 - val_acc: 0.3906

Epoch 9/10
Epoch 00009: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1282 - acc: 0.4333 - val_loss: 0.1227 - val_acc: 0.3906

Epoch 10/10
Epoch 00010: val_acc did not improve
- 0s - loss: 0.1295 - acc: 0.4208 - val_loss: 0.1234 - val_acc: 0.2266

acc: 22.66%
```

A small snapshot of two sequences of the application execution trace:

Each sample is having 8 features, first seven features are taken as inputs and last one is treated as output to be predicted.

sequence 1:

```
40 626979.9375 1196586.8750 16452.5000 3275.4375 519773.6875 1.6600 20.5535
40 692134.0000 1288955.4375 17689.7500 3352.3125 521722.0000 4.5441 43.7865
40 735489.6250 1336525.0625 17956.4375 3355.8750 522180.3750 3.0677 29.3883
40 779080.3125 1380106.4375 18235.3125 3357.3125 522605.8125 2.3105 19.5920
40 822905.4375 1423345.5625 18507.9375 3360.0000 522896.2500 10.8020 69.7630
40 866268.5625 1466615.0000 18773.5625 3362.8750 523337.1875 3.0905 19.2260
.......
```

sequence 2:

```
40 582271.0625 1035435.8750 16294.5000 1256.5000 357175.3750 3.7675 34.1337
40 686667.4375 1193365.5000 18752.4375 1340.9375 361748.1250 3.8250 33.8135
40 735528.9375 1252983.3125 19288.8125 1354.3750 363153.9375 2.7997 25.0650
40 778706.5000 1295276.5625 19533.8125 1355.8125 363278.3750 3.6734 35.2727
40 822147.1250 1340507.5625 19808.3750 1357.1250 363673.7500 3.3200 39.5510
```

.....
sequence n:

Comment: Do you mean "states" instead of "weights"? -- What makes you think the weights are getting reset?

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you. I mean to say, cell states are getting reset. I want training weights to be preserved for further tuning using next sequence. And depending on the training sequence sometimes the result is showing an increased accuracy and other times decreased accuracy.

Comment: I misinterpreted the result of the model. By digging into deep, I understood that the network's weights are getting updated on the subsequent sequence taking the previous sequence's network's weight as input.

Comment: One more doubt: as shown in the result above, why val_acc is getting improve starting from inf in the subsequent sequence?

Comment: `inf` usually appears if there is a division by zero. Probably the accuracy was the worst possible for that sequence before training.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you if I don't know exactly how your data is structured, what types of outputs you want, if you want the sequences to be connected or individual, what you consider a sequence, etc....

Comment: @Daniel Möller Thank you so much. I have updated my question with a small snapshot of two sequences(is stored in a separate files). I want each sequence to be treated as an individual as it represents a different execution trace of an application. And later sequences should be used for improving validation accuracy.